# Wiremock BodyPattern matching Contains this or that

Tags: json, testing, pattern-matching, matching, wiremock

I am trying to configure Wiremock to return the same response from a text file if the request body contains this or that etc. Here is my working file for a single request:

```
{
  "priority": 1,
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPath": "/v1/retrieve-vehicle",
    "bodyPatterns" : [ {
      "contains" : "\"vehicleIdentifier\":\"EROR-103\""
    } ]
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 404,
    "bodyFileName": "JsonFiles/NoVinFound-Error103.json",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried a few combinations of the bodyPatterns attribute (inspired by the documentation) but to no avail.

```
"bodyPatterns" : [ {
      "contains" : "\"vehicleIdentifier\":\"EROR-103\"",
      "contains" : "\"vehicleIdentifier\":\"EROR-103A\""
    } ]
```

```
"bodyPatterns" : [ {
      "contains" : "\"vehicleIdentifier\":\"EROR-103\""
      }, {
      "contains" : "\"vehicleIdentifier\":\"EROR-103A\""
    } ]
```

```
"multipartPatterns" : [ {
      "matchingType" : "ANY",
      "bodyPatterns" : [ {
        "contains" : "\"vehicleIdentifier\":\"EROR-103\"",
        "contains" : "\"vehicleIdentifier\":\"EROR-103A\""
      } ]
    } ]
```

```
"multipartPatterns" : [ {
      "matchingType" : "ANY",
      "bodyPatterns" : [ {
        "contains" : "\"vehicleIdentifier\":\"EROR-103\"" 
        }, {
        "contains" : "\"vehicleIdentifier\":\"EROR-103A\""
      } ]
    } ]
```

Please advise what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Try `"matches" : ".*\"vehicleIdentifier\":\"EROR-103A?\".*"`

Comment: I'm afraid that seems to have stopped all of my stubs. What is best practice for the priority field? I'm not convinced I'm using that right which isn't helping...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine found the solution. We needed a 'mappings tag' and then list full JSON objects as below.

```
{
  "mappings": [
    {
      "priority": 1,
      "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "urlPath": "/v1/retrieve-owner",
        "bodyPatterns" : [ {
          "matchesJsonPath": "$.[?($.vehicleIdentifier == 'VIN-A')]"

        } ]
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "bodyFileName": "JsonFiles/Exported-Vehicle.json",
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "priority": 1,
      "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "urlPath": "/v1/retrieve-owner",
        "bodyPatterns" : [ {
          "matchesJsonPath": "$.[?($.vehicleIdentifier == 'VIN-B')]"

        } ]
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "bodyFileName": "JsonFiles/Exported-Vehicle.json",
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `mappings` file will work, but there are a few caveats with that, and overall I'd suggest a different approach.

Instead, you could have a singular mapping file that matches based on a regex.

```
{
    "priority": 1,
    "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "urlPath": "/v1/retrieve-owner",
        "bodyPatterns" : [ {
            "matches": ".*\"vehicleIdentifer\": \"VIN-(A|B)\".*"
        } ]
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "bodyFileName": "JsonFiles/Exported-Vehicle.json",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
        }
    }
}
```

You may need to play around with getting the regex to match correctly, but this should work and allow you more flexibility. Say you had to add another match, you would only have to edit the regex, instead of adding a whole new mapping to the mappings file.

I also don't have as much experience with the matchesJsonPath, but you could also leverage that and have the regex match on the value there.

Here's my personal favorite tool for playing around with regex: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/)